# Rails 5 error: No route matches [DELETE] "/comments"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently trying to delete a comment the exact same way I can delete a post in my application. However, for some reason the exact same code does not seem to work for my comments an returns the following error:

**No route matches [DELETE] "/comments"**

```
def destroy
   @post = @comment.post
   @comment.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
   end
end
```

This is what my model looks like:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

This is what my route looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :posts
   resources :users
   resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]

   #signup and register workflow
   get '/signup' => 'users#new'
   get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
   post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
   delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

This is what my link in my view looks like (Slim):

```
   - @comments.each do |comment|
      .comment-container.level-0
        p 
        a href="/users/#{comment.user_id}" = comment.user.first_name
        | : 
        = comment.comment
        - if comment.user == current_user
          .icon-delete
            = link_to "Delete", comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
    end
    hr
    h3 Write a new comment
    = bootstrap_form_for(@comment) do |c|
      .field
        = c.text_field :comment
      .field
        = c.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id
        = c.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id
      .actions
        = c.submit
```

Comment: what is the output of `rake routes | grep comments` command?

Comment: comments POST   /comments(.:format)       comments#create

comment DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)   comments#destroy

Comment: @patrick  Can you post the code in your routes.rb file?

Comment: If you only have `create` and `destroy` actions, how do you render a `view` to create a new comment? Probably inside `posts/new.html.erb`. Then a `comment` is a nested rescource which is actually scoped to `posts`. A `comment` can't exist without a `post`. See http://blog.8thcolor.com/en/2011/08/nested-resources-with-independent-views-in-ruby-on-rails/ for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just missed the format of the `link_to` method:

```
= link_to "Delete", comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

It should be like: `link_to(body, url, html_options = {})`
You missed the **body** part.

Check [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

**EDIT**

> I just realised that when I posted this comment: If I try this, then
>   the error is: undefined method `post' for nil:NilClass

Ok, the problem is: When you click on the link it goes to the `destroy` method. Then it tries to query like `@post = @comment.post`. As you can see in the link you're sending `comment`. So in the destroy method you should fetch the `post` like:

```
def destroy
   @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
   @post = @comment.post
   @comment.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
   end
end
```

Then you'll be good to go. :)

Comment: Where did this `@comment` variable came from? Is this a single `Comment` object or a bunch of objects?

Comment: This link is inside the following loop:

 - @comments.each do |comment|

Comment: I just realised that when I posted this comment: If I try this, then the error is: undefined method `post' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Actually your problem is in the root where you've created the comment. I don't know how you creating the comments and what is the relation between the post and comments. It would be great if you post the relations and the whole `html` part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120898/discussion-between-emu-and-patrick).